# In a FX options book, is the sum of P&L equal to the portfolio value?

Tags: options, fx, portfolio

For a portfolio containing FX options, would the sum of P&L for each option be the portfolio value?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and as the FX market is suposed to never close, it can fluctuate 24/7, which makes it dangerous if you are not really aware of your exposure.